# MongoDB data not stored in /data/db, although it is saving data... but where?

Tags: mongodb, database

I'm completely new to MongoDB - I've installed all the programs and set it up so that I run mongod.exe and then mongo.exe. I created a new database called 'test' and inserted some data. However, I can't see any files being created in the /data/db directory. The data is definitely being stored somewhere, and when I closed down all the cmd boxes and started the processes again, the data I initially pushed onto the DB is still there.

I tried running the command 'db.adminCommand("getCmdLineOpts")' which apparently should show my DB Path, but it doesn't:
[image: mongo screenshot]

Can anyone offer some insight on this? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using mongod.exe without parameters default is `C:\data\db`. Check start up parameters if you run server as service.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason, I was expecting it to be within the directory that the MongoDB files were stored. Silly me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can run this command to retrieve the `dbpath` if you in a Linux environment:

```
grep dbpath /etc/mongod.conf
```

`db.adminCommand("getCmdLineOpts")` is not running the db path as it was not specified a a command line parameter when the `mongod` process was started. It seems the db path is configured in the `mongod.conf` configuration file and the above command should return it.